# can i define an iterator inside a while loop?

Tags: c++

My code has no compilation error. It seems to have a runtime error. In the following piece of code, when the while loop is executed for the first time everything works fine. But on the second iteration, everything stops at "list::iterator k = (temp2->store).begin();". When I comment out the "list::iterator k ..." part everything works fine. The variables temp2 and temp2->store are not NULL or empty. The debugger gave the following message "Unhandled exception at 0x009bc0cf in project euler.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xddddddf5".

```
 struct edge
{  int end1, end2;    
   ptr_to_edge *ptr_end1, *ptr_end2;
   edge *next, *l_chd, *r_chd; 
   edge(): next(NULL), l_chd(NULL), r_chd(NULL),  ptr_end1(NULL), ptr_end2(NULL)
  { }
};


   struct ptr_to_edge {
        int flag, vertex;    
        list<edge*> store;
        ptr_to_edge(): flag(1)
        { }
     };
 void parallel_reduction_step(ptr_to_edge *front, vector<edge> &a) {

  list<edge*>::iterator next = (front->store).begin();
  next++;
  list<edge*>::iterator current = (front->store).begin();
  list<edge*>::iterator last = (front->store).end();
  --last;

  while(current!= last) {

      if(((*current)->end1 == (*next)->end1)&&((*current)->end2==(*next)->end2)) {

             edge temp1;
             temp1.end1 = (*current)->end1; temp1.end2 = (*current)->end2;
             a.push_back(temp1);

             ptr_to_edge *temp2;
             if ((*current)->end1==front->vertex) 
                 temp2 = (*current)->ptr_end2;
             else 
                 temp2 = (*current)->ptr_end1; 

             list<edge*>::iterator k = (temp2->store).begin();

              current = (front->store).erase(j);
             *current = &(a.back());
             }
      else current++;
      next++;
      }
  };
```

Comment: Sorry.  Can't help you if I can't even read your post.

Comment: The first problem your code has is that you use too many one-letter variables and you nest too many blocks.  It is entirely unreadable.  Try using sensible variable names and breaking the function into component parts so that it is easier to comprehend and understand.

Comment: @user416689: What is the value of temp2 on that second time through?  And what is the value of temp2->store.  My guess is that either temp2 or temp2->store is NULL.

Comment: temp2 is a pointer to a struct variable and temp2->store is a list of struct pointers. They are not NULL.

Comment: You say it "stops" at "list::iterator k ...". What error are you getting? Segmentation fault? Bus Error? Have you tried using a debugger to step through to that point and observe the values of all the variables right before the crash?

Comment: @user416689: If your code is breaking, either something is NULL, or it is pointing to an invalid address.  When you replied, are you talking about values you observed in the debugger at runtime, or just what you expect them to point to?

Comment: @user416689: Also, some definition of the various structures you use in this code, and a very minimal set of boilerplate to reproduce your error would help a lot.

Comment: it says project name.exe has stopped working..i will try the debugger.

Comment: this is what the debugger said...

Unhandled exception at 0x009bc0cf in project euler.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xddddddf5.

Comment: I agree that it's likely that `temp2` is null or is pointing to garbage. (If you insist that `temp2` isn't null, then you should add `assert` to validate your claim.) Also, you say that commenting out that line avoids the crash, but you haven't done anything to narrow down which part of that line.  If you just had `list<edge*>::iterator k;` by itself, your code certainly wouldn't crash, and you wouldn't have had a flawed premise to your question.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the extra information you have provided here in the comments like the fact that temp2 and temp2->store are not NULL or empty, and the text of the error that the debugger gave you. It will help future readers who are having the same problem to find this question and (hopefully) the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for cleaning up the code.  It looks like you are pushing elements on vector a and then putting pointers to its elements in your other structures.  The problem with this is that resizes of "a" (which can occur as you add to it) will cause pointers (or iterators) to its elements to become invalid, and this can occur as you push elements on it.  I don't know if this is the problem you are having with the code, but it can cause problems.  You can change "a" to deque which won't invalidate pointers to its elements as you add to the end, and it should fix that part.

Comment: i have renamed the iterators. But iterator last(or m from the unedited post) is not the problem..

Comment: i will try it out and get back to you on it.. I have also included the struct definitions if that would be of any help..

Answer (score 0):

Some more details on the error message you are getting when your program aborts might be helpful, but I will make a wild guess anyway. If your `temp2` and `temp2->store` values are not NULL, then perhaps `temp2->store` is an empty container? That is, `temp2->store.begin() == temp2->store.end()`. You could try checking for that case before you attempt to dereference k. For example, you could change your while loop to

```
while(reached == 0 && k != temp2->store.end()) {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

If `temp2->store` is empty, then the begin iterator is equal to the end iterator, and dereferencing the end iterator is bad. So you should have a check to prevent it even if that ends up not being the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that it will ever be empty? In any use case of your code? I would still put that check in there even if it doesn't solve your problem. It will probably avoid another problem some time down the road.

Comment: added the k != temp2->store.end() part to the while condition . but the problem seems to persist.